# How can I run simultaneous instances of Clock.schedule_interval in kivy app?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a class that changes the background color constantly with a Clock.schedule_interval in **init**. I would like to create multiple instances of this class simultaneous; however, I think this means creating multiple threads which isn't allowed? What I would like is the top half to be changing colors while the bottom half is changing colors differently. What is happening is only the bottom half is changing colors while the top half is black. So here is the code.

The /teacher/main.py file is

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from random import randint

class ChangingBackgroundColor(Widget):
    r = NumericProperty(.5)
    g = NumericProperty(.5)
    b = NumericProperty(.5)
    a = NumericProperty(1)
    color = ReferenceListProperty(r, g, b, a)

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(ChangingBackgroundColor, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, .2)

    def update(self, dt):

        position = randint(0,2)  # change to randint(0,3) to change a as well
        direction = randint(0,1)

        if direction == 0:
            if self.color[position] == 0:
                self.color[position] += .1
            else:
                self.color[position] -= .1
        elif direction == 1:
            if self.color[position] == 1:
                self.color[position] -= .1
            else:
                self.color[position] += .1

        self.color[position] = round(self.color[position], 2)
        self.canvas.add(Color(self.color))

class TeachingApp(App):

    def build(self):
        grid = GridLayout(rows=2)
        a = ChangingBackgroundColor()
        b = ChangingBackgroundColor()
        grid.add_widget(a)
        grid.add_widget(b)
        return grid

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TeachingApp().run()
```

and the /teacher/teaching.kv file is

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<ChangingBackgroundColor>:
    canvas:
        Color: 
            rgba: self.color
        Rectangle:
            size: self.width, self.height
```

I looked here and and still fuzzy on the threading issue. [Clock documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html).

This is my first question I have submitted so if I did anything wrong regarding question submission please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, using Clock.schedule_interval doesn't use threads (it's all in the main thread), and can be used from other threads even if you did have them, although callbacks would still happen in the main thread.

The problem is that your Rectangle entry in the kv needs to have:

```
pos: self.pos
```

Without this, both rectangles have the default pos of (0, 0), so the second one is on top of the first one and the top half of the screen is black.

Comment: Wow thank you so much. Such an easy fix for something I thought was so hard.